# How to escape ampersand using laravel mail and gmail

Tags: php, laravel, gmail, sendinblue

I am using Laravel Mail for sending emails via SendInBlue. It was all working just fine but today I started to face an issue which was not present before.

Issue happens with a link generated in the blade email template.

This is example of code which generates the link:

```php
'link' => env('FRONT_APP').'verification?userid=25&code=12345'
```

The link is then being sent to Blade email template, and used as follows:

```html
<a href="{{ $link }}">PRESS TO CONTINUE</a>
```

However, after the email is delivered, the URL is actually:
`/verification?_se=YW5kcml1cy5rYlyeXMubHRAZ21haWuY39t&userid=25&amp%3Bcode=12345`

It seems that problem is with special character encoding of ampersand. However changing it to `&amp;` changes the URL to the following:
`/verification?_se=YW5kcml1cy5rYlyeXMubHRAZ21haWuY39t&userid=25&amp%3Bamp%3Bcode=12345`

I'm also not sure where this bit `_se=YW5kcml1cy5rYlyeXMubHRAZ21haWuY39t` comes from.
All of this wasn't happening before I started using SendInBlue.
I am using my Gmail account for sending emails to test.
Any ideas how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid escaping the string in your blade files, use `{!! !!}` instead of `{{ }}`

```
<a href="{!! $link !!}">PRESS TO CONTINUE</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an important element in your issue: you are sending emails through Sendinblue.
As stated in [their documentation](https://help.sendinblue.com/hc/en-us/articles/209421325-Why-is-the-URL-of-my-links-different-from-what-I-have-chosen-), Sendinblue updates the href to add their own tracking element so the attribute "_se" is probably added at that time.
But it should not be an issue (and it was probably the case before you started analysing this problem).

Regarding the escaping of "&" and in addition to N69S answer, you should first of all define at which step this character is escaped by checking the code generated by your view (simply add a `dd` statement **before** calling Sendinblue API).
Then you will know if you have to fix your PHP code or if you should instead ask Sendinblue support.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be resolved. It was on Sendinblue side. They introduced a bug when they added the «_se» parameter.

It has affected all links in emails sent between 15 and 16 September.